# Store variable based on loop index

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to do the following:

```
text_0="none"
text_1="none"
x = 0
for i in range (1,9):
 x = i%2
 if i%2 == 0:
   text = hello
 elif i%2 == 1:
   text = bonjour
 text_x = text
```

I'm trying to store `"hello"` or `"bonjour"` based on the index of `i` into either `text_0` or `text_1`. I know I could just put it into the `if` statement but I want to know if there is a way where we can change the `text_x` to `text_0` or `text_1` based on the value of `x`.

Comment: This is a code smell. Any time you are tempted to name variables like `text_0`, `text_1`... or similar, you should consider a `list` instead. Any time you are tempted to name variables like `text_jack`, `text_joan`, `text_peter`... or similar, you should consider a `dict` instead.

Comment: @Amadan is correct. Also note that `hello` and `bonjour` are not strings, they are variable names. You should enclose them in quotes (`"` or `'`) to make them string literals.

Comment: But, if for whatever reason you really really REALLY need to do it, then you could use `globals()['text_'+str(x)] = text`. Keep in mind that this is a solution no one will ever advise you to use, literally anything else you can come up with to do it will be better.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. You can put `x` into its own class then overload `__getattrs__` to change `text_` whenever `x` changes.

```
text_0 = "none"
text_1 = "none"
class VariableTrigger:
    def VariableTrigger(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def __setattrs__(self, name, value):
        if(name == "x"):
            if(value == 1):
                text_0 = "hello"
            if(value == 0):
                text_0 = "bonjour"
        self.__dict__[name] = value
the_x = VariableTrigger(0)
print(text_0) //prints 'hello'
the_x.x = 1
print(text_0)  //prints 'bonjour'
```

The long answer is that this is hacky and too complicated for what you're trying to do and you should just use an `if` statement.